# Sending variables to sqldatasource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have an sqldatasource that takes a stored procedure with a parameter..But that the stored procedure doesnt get executed...

Am I passing the parameter successfully?

SQLDataSource:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" 
        SelectCommand="GetMessagesTitles" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The pageLoad code behind:

```
  string name = ModeratorUsefulFunctions.GetMessageUsersName(g);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Name", name);
```

The stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetMessagesTitles

   @Name nvarchar(50)

AS
    SELECT MessageTitle, MessageID
    FROM Messages
    WHERE MessageTo=@Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters value instead of adding the parameter in the SQLDataSource. Since you have already added the parameter in the `SelectParameters` Collection, you only need to pass the value. The way you are doing, it adds another Select parameter, that's the problem.

It should be like..

```
string name = ModeratorUsefulFunctions.GetMessageUsersName(g);

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["name"].DefaultValue = name;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... The 'n' should be 'N'..this corrects the situation..The answer was right..thanks